# Mongo Go Driver - Inline with Embedded Structs Not working

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go

While working on Golang Mongo Driver, I am stuck with this weird beahviour to use `inline`

Seems like `bson:",inline"` doesnt work with `Embedded Structs`.

Not able to understand why such a behaviour?

`inline     Inline the field, which must be a struct or a map,
           causing all of its fields or keys to be processed as if
           they were part of the outer struct. For maps, keys must
           not conflict with the bson keys of other struct fields.`

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

//Expected Output
//{
//  "ID": "5e6e96cb3cfd3c0447d3e368",
//  "product_id": "5996",
//  "Others": {
//      "some": "value"
//  }
//}

//Actual Output
//{
//  "ID": "5e6e96cb3cfd3c0447d3e368",
//  "product_id": "5996"
//}

type Product struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId string             `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    *SchemalessDocument
}

type SchemalessDocument struct {
    Others    bson.M             `bson:",inline"`
}


func main() {

    clientOptions := options.ClientOptions{
        Hosts: []string{"localhost"},
    }
    client, _ = mongo.NewClient(&clientOptions)
    client.Connect(context.TODO())
    var p Product
    collection := client.Database("Database").Collection("collection")
    query := bson.D{{"product_id", "5996"}}
    _ = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), query).Decode(&p)

    jsonResp, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonResp))

}
```

But the same code works if I change

```
type Product struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId string             `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    Others    bson.M             `bson:",inline"`
}
```

Comment: Try with type Product struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId string             `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    Document  *Schemaless `bson:"others"`
}

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 Its not working . Have you tried it? Is it working for you? I am still getting `{"ID":"5e6e96cb3cfd3c0447d3e368","product_id":"5996","Document":null}` or `{"ID":"5e6e96cb3cfd3c0447d3e368","product_id":"5996","Document":{"Others":null}}`

Comment: Can you post your example data in DB?

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 It is unstructured document like `{
 
 "_id":"",
 "product_id":"",
 "some":"value",
 "some_more":"value2"
}` , But i want to convert it to Struct for fields which I know and rest to a map using `inline`

Comment: The ``bson:",inline"`` exposes for 1 level.  if you put the inline tag in ``SchemalessDocument``, the mongodb driver will expose out for 1 level which is the bson.M so the result still will be m:{....}.  That the reason why your second code works, because it exposes 1 level down to map[string]interface{}.

Comment: about the put all things into one struct, do you have any reason to do that?

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 I dnt have schema of document, so I want to construct partial schema and rest would be as `bson.M`. But problem is `bson:inline` doesnt work for Embedded Structs, so I have to add this with every struct as stated in second part of code. 

I wanted to add it once in Base class only

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 Also, can you demonstrate in the code what do you mean by `inline tag in SchemalessDocument ` . I tried but still i dont get any values in `SchemalessDocument` `Others` is `nil`

Comment: With inline tag in SchemalessDocument, it only works when json in DB like:
{
  "ID": "5e6e96cb3cfd3c0447d3e368",
  "product_id": "5996",
   "Others": { // you should point the name "Others" in your SchemalessDocument 
       "some": "value"
  }
}
it will expose list off fields in the Others into SchemalessDocument

Comment: The only way, I can think, is you can use
type Product struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId string             `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    Others   map[string] interface{} `bson:",inline"`
}

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 Thats correct. My question was this only, why `inline` is not working when it is inside `Embedded Struct`. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 6):

This is what it should be

```
type Product struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId string             `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    *SchemalessDocument          `bson:",inline"`
}

type SchemalessDocument struct {
    Others    bson.M             `bson:"others"`
}
```